# Why are my infowindow empty?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi ive maked a google map api v3 map with 2 infowindow onclick on the marquer,

But the infowindows are empty :

```
        var carte = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Gmap"), options);
    var marqueur = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.546993,5.441062),
        map: carte
    });
            var marqueur2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.529038, 5.45251),
        map: carte
                });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div id='content' style='color:#000 !important'>Hammam des Prêcheurs, 10 rue Felicien David 13100 Aix en Provence</div>"
    });

        var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<div id='content2' style='color:#000 !important'>Salle Clos Beaufort 560, Rte Puy Ste Réparade, 13540 Puyricard</div>"
    });
        infowindow.open(carte, marqueur);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marqueur, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.open(carte, marqueur);
    });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marqueur2, 'click', function() {

        infowindow2.open(carte, marqueur2);
    });
```

Any idea to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: works for me (the text is black on a white background).  You must be doing something else outside of what you posted.

Comment: yes but here it dont works  http://lapasserelle-massage.fr/index.php?p=../pages/formation.php&r=11  click on the green picto on the right

Comment: Looks like css to me.  Don't have the tools right now to say for sure.

Comment: I went full retard and had white text on white background... lol... you never go full retard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this css rule (in [style.css](http://lapasserelle-massage.fr/css/style.css)):

```
style.css:10
* { 
    z-index: 10;   
}
```